# Ошибка wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает данная ошибка?

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Cherry_Dynamic_Css_Utilities::typography_font_family(), 0 passed in /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php on line 487 and exactly 1 expected in /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/inc/class-cherry-dynamic-css-utilities.php:688 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php(487): Cherry_Dynamic_Css_Utilities->typography_font_family() #1 [internal function]: Cherry_Dynamic_Css->replace_func(Array) #2 /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php(327): preg_replace_callback('/@(([a-zA-Z_]+)...', Array, '/* #Typography ...') #3 /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_ in /storage/ssd2/320/6060320/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/inc/class-cherry-dynamic-css-utilities.php on line 688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка означает ровно то, что написано: `cherry-team-members/cherry-framework/modules/cherry-dynamic-css/cherry-dynamic-css.php в строке 487` вызвал фукнцию `Cherry_Dynamic_Css_Utilities::typography_font_family()` без аргументов, в то время как код этой функции ожидает ровно 1 аргумент.

Дальше приведён стек вызовов, который заканчивается в том же плагине. Причём этот стек не полный, должны быть ещё вызовы самого WordPress.

Почему такая ошибка стала возникать, сказать невозможно без полного кода плагина. Возможно, сменилась версия php или базы, или обновилось ядро WP. Возможно, ошибка вызвана какими-то новыми настройками плагина или темы.

Вам нужен специалист, который умеет пользоваться отладчиком.